# Eclipse & Tomcat: How to deploy a project to differently named directory

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am using Eclipse Juno. I'd like to know how, if possible, to deploy a workspace project ('Foo') to a folder under Tomcat called 'Bar'.

Some points to note:

- Project name in eclipse: `Foo`
- Folder that gets created when I publish: `$TOMCAT/wtpwebapps/Foo`
- Folder that I wish to be created: `$TOMCAT/wtpwebapps/Bar`
- I have set the '*Context Root*' under '*Web Project Settings*' to `Bar`
- The project has the '*Dynamic Web Module*' facet applied.

I am not asking about the way in which I would access this project via the webserver (ie., `http://localhost:8080/Foo` vs `http://localhost:8080/Bar`).  I explicitly mean the name of the folder to which the content is deployed.

MyEclipse is able to do this.  I don't want to use MyEclipse, so would love to know how to achieve this using the vanilla version.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: May I ask *why* you need that feature as I cannot think of any use case?

Comment: I suppose it largely down to curiosity, but also fuelled by the fact that that's just How It Is in the default environment of the rest of the team. I would have a tough time suggesting a change if I'm unable to first make it work as is.

Comment: You are correct though, in that there probably aren't many good use cases. Unless there are hard coded dependencies, which would be stupid, but we've all seen stupid happen!

Answer (score 0):

Open the project's Properties dialog (either from its context menu or the main Project menu with that project selected) and change the context root on the Web Project Settings page.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I've already tried that. It still deploys to a folder (on the filesystem) called 'Foo'.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script which copy your `/desired_folder` to your `desired_directory` and call that script in your code at the end or somewhere in eclipse properties after compilation or execution.It may works fine

Comment: Thanks SSK, but this isn't really what I'm trying to do.  This idea is to change as little as possible - Just want to be able to configure Eclipse to assemble and deploy in the same way (however bad) as MyEclipse is currently set up to do.